Flutter OneContext error "OneContext not initiated! please use builder method"
When I first run the application or restart it, this error appears in the console. I tried a few things but it didn't work. Any solution please?
This is main.dart:
void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    OnePlatform.app = () => const MyApp();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: ...,
        builder: OneContext().builder,
        navigatorKey: OneContext().key,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: false,
        ),
        home: const HomePage()
      ),
    );
  }


Flutter version: 3.22.2
OneContext version: 4.0.0




Always check the error properly. You might get valuable info in the
error to solve the issue. The solution was pointed out in the Error log.

Wrap your app with OneContext in main -
void main() {
  runApp(OneContext().builder(child: MyApp()));
}

And from MaterialApp -
Remove builder: OneContext().builder

OneContext().builder() function requires context, so didn't work.

Keep your previous implementation. And try,
flutter clean
flutter pub get

It didn't work either...

What's the error now? I just tried it on a fresh project and worked with just two lines of code.

Please try removing "OnePlatform.app" from the main function, and rerun the app. Keep the MaterialApp as it is

The error is the same as the screenshot. I tried everything (I removed OnePlatform.app too) but the error does not change. This error does not prevent the app from working but it keeps appearing in the console. I am going crazy.

Can you use onecontext's dialog or snackbar?

Also, after removing OnePlatform.app. Close the running app > flutter clean > flutter pub get > then run the app again
